# Fixed-Point Iteration Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fixed-point-iteration

This is a mathematica code for fixed point iteration.

```
expr={1,0,9999};
f[{i_,xi_,err_}]:=(xipp=0.2062129*(20+(2*xi))^(2/5);
  {i+1,xipp,Abs[(((xipp-xi)/(xipp))*100)]});
NestWhileList[f,expr,#[[3]]>=.05&]
```

If I were to prove this converges for all initial guesses would I use the same code and replace the function with its derivative?

Comment: not a programming question, try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Looks like `xipp = xi^(2/5)` works too.  Can you take a derivative including `Abs`?